# How does group by nested array with parent and child?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have problem with array JSON. I think it nested group by the first is group by **_id** and second one is group by **itemId** I do not know how to solve it,Please help me

```
 let data=[
   {
    "_id" : "013",
    "items" : [
        {
            "itemId" : "4",
            "stockIn" : 50,
            "stockOut" : 0
        },
        {
            "itemId" : "9",
            "stockIn" : 100,
            "stockOut" : 0
        }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id" : "013",
    "items" : [
        {
            "itemId" : "3",
            "noFreeQtyCount" : 20,
            "freeQtyCount" : 0
        },
        {
            "itemId" : "9",
            "noFreeQtyCount" : 30,
            "freeQtyCount" : 0
        }
    ]
  }
 ]
```

This is my data that I want

```
[
   {
    "_id" : "013",
    "items" : [
        {
            "itemId" : "3",
            "noFreeQtyCount" : 20,
            "freeQtyCount" : 0
        },
        {
            "itemId" : "4",
            "stockIn" : 50,
            "stockOut" : 0
        },
        {
            "itemId" : "9",
            "stockIn" : 100,
            "stockOut" : 0
            "noFreeQtyCount" : 30,
            "freeQtyCount" : 0
        }
    ]
  },
 ]
```

This my script please help

```
 const groupBy = data.reduce((acc, cur) => {
acc[cur._id] ? acc[cur._id].items = [...acc[cur._id].items, ...cur.items] : acc[cur._id] = cur;
return acc;
 }, {});
```

const output = groupBy;
print(output);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.key()`, `Array.prototype.map()` and `Object.assign()` accomplish the grouping you need.

Refer the code below:

```js
    function groupByItemId(data) {
  const mergedData = {};

  data.forEach(entry => {
    const _id = entry["_id"];
    const items = entry["items"];

    if (!mergedData[_id]) {
      mergedData[_id] = {};
    }

    items.forEach(item => {
      const itemId = item["itemId"];

      if (!mergedData[_id][itemId]) {
        mergedData[_id][itemId] = {};
      }

      Object.assign(mergedData[_id][itemId], item);
    });
  });

  const result = Object.keys(mergedData).map(_id => {
    return {"_id": _id, "items": Object.values(mergedData[_id])};
  });

  return result;
}

const inputData = [
  {
    "_id": "013",
    "items": [
      {"itemId": "4", "stockIn": 50, "stockOut": 0},
      {"itemId": "9", "stockIn": 100, "stockOut": 0},
    ],
  },
  {
    "_id": "013",
    "items": [
      {"itemId": "3", "noFreeQtyCount": 20, "freeQtyCount": 0},
      {"itemId": "9", "noFreeQtyCount": 30, "freeQtyCount": 0},
    ],
  },
];

const result = groupByItemId(inputData);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank for your script that what I need.

Comment: Glad to help :-)